# hashid encryption returning no value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, hash, hashids, bin2hex

Was trying to encrypt text:- "Michael Fehr" or "carpet" using [hashids](https://hashids.org/php/), it returns blank.

Code:-

```
$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids("mysalt");
$hashed_text = $hashids->encode_hex(bin2hex("Michael Fehr"));

echo "<script>alert('".$hashed_text."')</script>";
```

Also tried:- `$hashed_interestrate = $hashids->encode_hex("63706b64");`, but not working.
If I try text:- "CPC", it's working.

Comment: Two bugs on first sight: "c445def"seems not to be a valid hex string (just 5 chars) and what should be the result of "bin2hex" - I think you should use "hex2bin"

Comment: @MichaelFehr okay, so not to be confused, I am trying `$hashids->encode_hex(bin2hex("Michael Fehr"));` but it also returns blank.